# Is there a way to calculate price by summing a search by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am a beginner in the world of rails, and even in the world of ruby so please be patient...

So I have this DB Schema:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20201130233206) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "total"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "fki_productid_fkey", using: :btree
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "fki_store_fk", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "sku"
    t.string   "tipo"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_products_on_store_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "email",      default: "francisco.abalan@pjchile.com"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                          null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "orders", "products", name: "productid_fkey"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "stores", name: "store_fk"
  add_foreign_key "products", "stores"
end
```

The idea was: order has one to too many products & one-2-one with stores. Therefore one order, many products, 1 store. Same logic applies for products and stores.

I populated this db with this seed:

```
store = Store.create([{id: 1, name: "La reina", address: "Irarrazaval", phone: "12232332"}, {id: 2, name: "La florida", address: "Walker Martinez", phone: "12332"} ])
Product.create([{name: "Pizza de la reina", store: store.first}, {name: "Pizza de la florida", store: store.second}])
```

How do i code & where do i code the calculation for order in which it should be (at least in my mind is) something like this:

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @products = Product.find([:first_product, :second_product]).sum
        @order = Order.find(params([:id]))
        render json: @order + @products
    end
```

Again, I'm extremely sorry for being so vague so if you want to upload more, I'll do it pretty quickly.

Edit 1:
Models:
order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :store, optional: true
  has_many :product, optional: true

end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store, optional: true
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
end
```

store.rb

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product
end
```

Controllers:

order_controller.rb

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @products = Product.find([:first_product, :second_product]).sum
        @order = Order.find(params([:id]))
        render json: @order + @products
    end
    def new
        @order = Order.new
    end
     def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def sum
        @products = Product.find(params[:first_product, :second_product]).sum
        @order = Order.find(params([:id]))
        render json: @order + @products
    end

private
    def orders_params
    #Brings store table and asks for params
    params.permit(:id, :first_product, :second_product, :store_id);
  end
end
```

product_controller.rb

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @product = Product.all
        render json: @product
    end

    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)
        if @product.save!
            render json: @product
        end
    end
    def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      render json: @product
    else
      render json: @product
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    render json: @product
  end
    private

    def product_params
    #Brings product table and asks for params
        params.permit(:name, :sku, :tipo, :price, :store_id);
    end
end
```

store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @store = Store.all
        render json: @store
    end

    def new
        @store = Store.new
    end

    def create
        @store = Store.new(store_params)
        if @store.save!
            render json: @store
        end
    end

    def show
        @store = Store.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @store = Store.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @store = Store.find(params[:id])
        if @store.update(store_params)
          render json: @store
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @store = Store.find(params[:id])
        @store.destroy
        render json: @store
    end
    
private

  def store_params
    #Brings store table and asks for params
    params.permit(:name, :address, :email, :phone);
  end
end
```

So, I made it through. To begin with, my models and relationships were all over the place. I also was missing an intermediate table between orders and products.
After that my sum method changed a bit but the idea was there.
Thank you so much to everyone that tried to help me here.
Also I wanted to say thanks to Harry, the misterious discord friend that guided me through everything and helped me with a lot of patience. To you Harry, you deserve everything <3

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is rather unclear what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Unrelated with your question, but you have a big problem because you don't have an intermediate table between orders and products. Also, please add the view where you want to display the totals (I guess the orders view?) instead of irrelevant controllers that probably have nothing to do with your problem. Cheers

Comment: Hello there...! @Eyeslandic Thank u so much for your comment. As I already solved it, I'll try to share how in the living hell I made it through.

Comment: @AlterLagos This is the most accurate rn. I was absolutely missing the intermediate table between those 2. That was the key to cracking up the problem.

Comment: @IgnacioGonzalez Rails can be hard to begin with, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in the method below you would like to find all products matching some criterias and calculate total price

```
def sum
    @products = Product.find(params[:first_product, :second_product]).sum
    @order = Order.find(params([:id]))
    render json: @order + @products
end
```

I would try sth like this:

```
Product.where(id: [first_product.id, second_product.id]).sum(:price)
```

Just use `where` method instead of `find` with array of ids :)

- update1: I did not check rest of the code....
- update2: Please do not forget, that using integer for price means that in fact this will price in cents - so i would rename the column to price_cents :)